# Use Entity framework I want to include only first children objects and not child of child(sub of sub)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Useing Entity framework I want to include an only the first level of children objects and not the children of child

I have these two classes:

```
public class BusinessesTBL
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OffersTBL> OffersTBLs { get; set; }
}

public class OffersTBL 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CatId { get; set; }

    public string BusinessesTBLID { get; set; }
    public virtual BusinessesTBL BusinessesTBLs { get; set; }
}
```

when I try to bring all offers according to CatId field, I need to return the BusinessesTBLs also, but the method also return offers again per each BusinessesTBL obj , My code is :

```
public IQueryable<OffersTBL> GetOffersTBLsCat(int id)
{
    db.OffersTBLs.Include(s => s.BusinessesTBLs);
}
```

You can see the wrong result on : 
http://mycustom.azurewebsites.net/api/OffersApi/GetOffersTBLsCat/4

As you can see it return all offers under each Business object while business object under each offer, And I want only to return offers with its Business object without offer under Business obj.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: I also tried to use this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  but doesn't change any thing

Comment: The link in your question is dead. Which goes to show that it's always better to include results etc. as text in the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I now see that a big part of the original answer is nonsense.

Sure enough, the reason for the endless loop is relationship fixup. But you can't stop EF from doing that. Even when using `AsNoTracking`, EF performs relationship fixup in the objects that are materialized *in one query*. Thus, your query with `Include` will result in fully populated navigation properties `OffersTBLs` and  `BusinessesTBLs`.

The message is simple: if you don't want these reference loops in your results, you have to project to a view model or DTO class, as in [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30366778/861716). An alternative, less attractive in my opinion, when serialization is in play, is to configure the serializer to ignore reference loops. Yet another less attractive alternative is to get the objects separately with `AsNoTracking` and selectively populate navigation properties yourself.

---

**Original answer:**

This happens because Entity Framework performs *relationship fixup*, which is the process that auto-populates navigation properties when the objects that belong there are present in the context. So with a circular references you could drill down navigation properties endlessly even when lazy loading is disabled. The Json serializer does exactly that (but apparently it's instructed to deal with circular references, so it isn't trapped in an endless loop).

The trick is to prevent relationship fixup from ever happing. Relationship fixup relies on the context's `ChangeTracker`, which caches objects to track their changes and associations. But if there's nothing to be tracked, there's nothing to fixup. You can stop tracking by calling `AsNoTracking()`:

```
db.OffersTBLs.Include(s => s.BusinessesTBLs)
             .AsNoTracking()
```

If besides that you also disable lazy loading on the context (by setting `contextConfiguration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`) you will see that only `OffersTBL.BusinessesTBLs` are populated in the Json string and that `BusinessesTBL.OffersTBLs` are empty arrays.

A bonus is that `AsNoTracking()` increases performance, because the change tracker isn't busy tracking all objects EF materializes. In fact, you should always use it in a disconnected setting.

Answer (score 10):

You have deactivated lazy loading on OffersTBLs making it non-virtual. What if you activate lazy loading? like this:

```
public class BusinessesTBL
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    //put a virtual here
    public virtual ICollection<OffersTBL> OffersTBLs { get; set; }
}
```

Then, be sure to not call/include OffersTBLs when serializing. If the OffersTBLs are still returning, it is because you are fetching them somewhere in your code. If this is happening, edit your question and paste all the code, including the serializing logic.

Answer (score 3):

Since OffersTBL has an association to BusinessesTBL and BusinessesTBL to OffersTBL you can loop infinitly throw the Entities like OffersTBL.BusinessesTBL.OffersTBL.BusinessesTBL and so on.

To control the nested depth of the Entities i'm usually using helperclasses with the needed properties in them.

For BusinessesTBL

```
public class BusinessesTBLHelper
{
    private BusinessesTBLHelper(BusinessesTBL o){
        ID = o.ID;
        FirstName = o.FirstName;
        lastName = o.LastName;
        OffersTBLids = new List<int>();

        foreach(OffersTBL offersTbl in o.OffersTBLs){
            OffersTBLids.Add(offersTbl.ID);
        }
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> OffersTBLids { get; set; } //no references anymore
}
```

And same for your OffersTBL Entity.

```
public class OffersTBLHelper
{
    private OffersTBLHelper(OffersTBL o){
        ID = o.ID;
        Name = o.Name;
        CatId = o.CatId;
        BusinessesTBLID = o.BusinessesTBLID;
        BusinessesTBLs = new BusinessesTBLHelper(o.BusinessesTBLs);
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public intCatId{ get; set; }

    public string BusinessesTBLID { get; set; }
    public BusinessesTBLHelper BusinessesTBLs { get; set; }
}
```

On quering database you can directly create the new helperobjects from queryresult:

```
public IEnumerable<OffersTBLHelper> GetOffersTBLsCat(int id)
{
    return db.OffersTBLs.where(s => s.CatId == id).Select(x=> new OffersTBLHelper(x)).ToList();
}
```

Now you have all the OffersTBL with BusinessesTBLs under. The loop stops here because the BusinessesTBLs have no OffersTBL under it. However, it only has them Ids in a List for further referencing and identifying.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the object isnt null and just empty:

```
 public IQueryable<OffersTBL> GetOffersTBLsCat(int id)
 {
     db.OffersTBLs.Include(s => s.BusinessesTBLs).Where(x => !x.BusinessesTBLs.OffersTBLs.Any());
 }
```

Edit:  Filter before the include:

```
public IQueryable<OffersTBL> GetOffersTBLsCat(int id)
{
     db.OffersTBLs.Where(x => !x.BusinessesTBLs.OffersTBLs.Any())
         .Include(s => s.BusinessesTBLs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, I tried your line, but it return nothing!

Comment: I need to return the two first levels, offers and the business obj for each one offer, but not return three levels by also show all offers related to each business as level three!

Comment: How is your db object loaded?  If you step into the method is there anything within db.OffersTBLs?

Comment: each one BusinessesTBL obj has many offers (offers are many in relation), in my code I made OffersTBLs.Include(s => s.BusinessesTBLs) to bring the parent Business obj and return it with each offer, but as you can see it return the offer then the business joined to it then all offers related to business !

Comment: I've edited my answer, it looks like you need to filter it first and then do the include to load the related entities.

Comment: Sorry, it is also return null array! Are you sure from using Where

Comment: I've just been playing with this in LinqPad. It looks like the OffersTBLs object isn't actually empty but just has an empty record, so the !Any() will not work and the other query will just return everything.  This explains the issue https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/08/linq-query-operators-and-null-lists/ one way around this is to possibly check the first object. Where(x => x.BusinessesTBLs.OffersTBLs.FirstOrDefault().ID != 0) but this has it's obvious limitations.