# Entity Framework Core returns all nested children when using .Include() on a Many-To-Many Mapping Entity query

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0.0. When I query my context using the .Include() statement on navigation properties of a many-to-many mapping entity, the context returns all children of children of children... for the navigation properties of this mapping entity.

Example:

```
MapExerciseWorkout queryResult;
using (var context = new FitnessContext("MySqlConnectionString"))
{
    queryResult = context
        .MapExerciseWorkout.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(i => i.Exercise).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(i => i.Workout).AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult,
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    });
```

I can confirm that navigation properties of Exercise and Workout that are NOT related to the Mapping Entity "MapExericseWorkout", for example ExerciseHistories and WorkoutHitories, are not loaded and therefore returned as *null*.

I expect "result" of the above example query to be:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Workout": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "WorkoutA",
    "MapExerciseWorkout": null,
    "WorkoutHistories": null,
    "OwnerGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  "WorkoutId": 1,
  "Exercise": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "ExerciseA",
    "ExerciseType": 0,
    "MapExerciseWorkout": null,
    "ExerciseHistories": null,
    "OwnerGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  "ExerciseId": 1,
  "OwnerGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

But instead get a fully recursive MapExerciseWorkout for the included Exercise and Workout:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Workout": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "WorkoutA",
    "MapExerciseWorkout": [{"Id":2,"WorkoutId":1,"Exercise":{"Id":2,"Name":"ExerciseB","ExerciseType":0,"MapExerciseWorkout":[{"Id":4,"Workout":{"Id":2,"Name":"WorkoutB","MapExerciseWorkout":[{"Id":3,"WorkoutId":2,"Exercise":{"Id":1,"Name":"ExerciseA","ExerciseType":0,"MapExerciseWorkout":[],"ExerciseHistories":null,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"ExerciseId":1,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],"WorkoutHistories":null,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"WorkoutId":2,"ExerciseId":2,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],"ExerciseHistories":null,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"ExerciseId":2,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],
    "WorkoutHistories": null,
    "OwnerGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  "WorkoutId": 1,
  "Exercise": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "ExerciseA",
    "ExerciseType": 0,
    "MapExerciseWorkout": [{"Id":3,"Workout":{"Id":2,"Name":"WorkoutB","MapExerciseWorkout":[{"Id":4,"WorkoutId":2,"Exercise":{"Id":2,"Name":"ExerciseB","ExerciseType":0,"MapExerciseWorkout":[{"Id":2,"Workout":{"Id":1,"Name":"WorkoutA","MapExerciseWorkout":[],"WorkoutHistories":null,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"WorkoutId":1,"ExerciseId":2,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],"ExerciseHistories":null,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"ExerciseId":2,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],"WorkoutHistories":null,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"WorkoutId":2,"ExerciseId":1,"OwnerGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],
    "ExerciseHistories": null,
    "OwnerGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  "ExerciseId": 1,
  "OwnerGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

The returned nested children of MapExerciseWorkout are not indefinite, but is way too much data and I don't want and don't need them to be returned.

I tried the following without success:

- According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186315/in-entity-framework-i-want-to-include-only-first-children-objects-and-not-child) SO question, I added .AsNoTracking() to the query
- I removed the "virtual" keyword from all navigation properties
- I wrapped the context query in a using statement promoting a disposed context
- I wanted to disable lazy loading for the context, but EF Core does not seem to offer it by design, so there is no need to disable it

How can I include only the Exercise and Workout without their navigation properties to include their respective MapExerciseWorkout?

Comment: When using `x.Include(x => x.y)`, the inverse navigation property `y.x` is also populated. This is "by design" (part of the so called navigation property fixup) and cannot be changed. In order to have full control of what gets serialized, use DTOs and projection.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I don't worry about the serialization, but I worry about the performance impact of the query on the SQL database and the size of the returned data. The way EF Core is designed atm, this unwanted population of the inverse navigation property behavior can consume the vast majority of resources required to execute this simple query - performance and size wise, isn't that so? This seems unnecessary to me, especially after disposing the context.