# EF Core self joined ICollection query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, ef-core-5.0

I have a problem with querying data from a self reference datatable having an ICollection.

Here are my table structures:

```
public class SoqHeading 
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string ItemNo { get; set; } 
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        
        public SoqRevision SoqRevision_NP { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SoqItem> Items { get; set; }

        public int? ParentSoqHeadingId { get; set; }
        public SoqHeading Parent_NP { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SoqHeading> Children_NP { get; set; }
}

public class SoqItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SoqPreliminaryOrContract_enum PreliminaryOrContract { get; set; }
    
     
    public int SoqHeadingId { get; set; }
    
    public SoqHeading SoqHeading_NP { get; set; }
}
```

I have a self referenced relation in the `SoqHeading` table which is 1 to many. The `SoqHeading` table can have zero or many `SoqItems`.

This is how the data is in my database

[image]

what i want is to query all from the root node of the SoqHeading table with its children and the items.

like this

```
 {
    "ItemNo": "C",
    "Items": [
      {
        "ItemNo": "c-1",
      },
      {
        "ItemNo": "c-2",
      }
    ],
    "Children_NP": [
      {
        "ItemNo": "C.1",
        "Children_NP": [
          {
            "ItemNo": "C.1.1",
            "Items": [
              {
                "ItemNo": "c.1.1-1",
              },
              {
                "ItemNo": "c.1.1-2",
              }
            ],
            "Children_NP": [],
          },
          {
            "ItemNo": "C.1.2",
            "Items": [
              {
                "ItemNo": "c.1.2-1",
              },
              {
                "ItemNo": "c.1.2-2",
              }
            ],
            "Children_NP": [],
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "ItemNo": "C.2",
        "Children_NP": [],
      }
    ]
  }
```

But currently i get data from the query like this

```
[
  {
    "ItemNo": "C"
  },
  {
    "ItemNo": "C.1.2",
  }
]
```

where C.1.2 has to be inside C, but it not. C and C.1.2 are in the same level which i dont wont to have produced by the following query

```
var entity = await _context.SoqHeadings
                            .Include(i=>i.Items)
                            .Include(i => i.Children_NP)
                            .Where(w => w.SoqRevision_NP.ProjectId == 10)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

please help

Comment: A JSON representation is not the best way to show what you want, but I assume [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30186315/861716) is your problem.

Comment: Could you please clear your jsons  and leave only important properties. It is hard to figure what you have and what you want.

Comment: @GertArnold, thanks for the try, but that is not my problem

Comment: @Serge, i have updated the question. please check and let me know if this is clear now

Comment: @thanzeel Thank you very much, at least now we can see the structrure. But I think you have to leave the full jsons too, in order  the people could test the code

Comment: @Serge, i tried to leave the full json, but the size of the body exceeds and i cannot post the question. is there any other alternative that i can provide you the full json?

Comment: Then you need some sort of recursive querying. There are many similar question, look for LINQ + recursive or hierarchy.

Comment: @GertArnold , thanks for the reply. it helped me solve my issue, and that is what i exactly needed. I got the answer from here https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/20974248/recursive-hierarchy---recursive-query-using-linq
 `var categories = _context.ProductCategories .Include(e => e.ProductInCategory) .ThenInclude(e => e.Product) .AsEnumerable() .Where(e => e.ParentId == null) .ToList();` the problem stated in the link is exactly as mine. **but is this effiecient? can ef core 5 do better?**

Comment: @GertArnold, please help us if you are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems to be EFcore has no support to included the children on the first child node  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14144

so the work around is something like this here https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server