# How to disable autoincludes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I call

```
_dbContext.Employees
            .Include(e => e.Company)
            .Where(e => e.IsDelete == false)
```

I get model `Employee` with a `Company` inside, which contains an `Employee`, and that has a `Company` and so on - endlessly

This causes an error:

> A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee.Company.Employee

Solution with `JsonConvert` works, but it's not suitable

```
 ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
```

it is advisable to solve this issue on the EF side

Comment: *but not suitable* -- Why not? It's your only option, EF is not going to change this *relationship fixup*. Or use DTOs that don't have this circular reference.

Comment: because it will affect the other models

Comment: @CodeCaster Reopened. It's not about lazy loading. It's another common problem (relationship fixup causing circular references) which has other duplicates.

Comment: *because it will affect the other models* -- Then you should project to DTOs and serialize those. Better to do that anyway. I consider this a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30186315/861716

Comment: @Gert they ask how to disable "autoincludes" i.e. lazy loading, right? If their question is "how to return DTOs instead of entities" then I agree it's a different question, but that's not what they ask. Edit: ah it is a circular reference due to autofixup, my bad.

Comment: @CodeCaster Where OP uses the phrase "autoincludes" they actually mean relationship fixup. At any rate, w/o lazy loading the query they show is enough to get circular references. Lazy loading tends to cause other problems in serialization (i.e. an explosion of generated queries, timeouts, memory exceptions).

Comment: Add AsNoTracking(), it will solve the issue